# (SOLVED) C 2D Array: Finding Max from each row and Min from each column

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am creating a program to print out the maximum value of each row and the minimum value of each column of an NxN 2D array.

So, for example I have this 4x4 2D array:

```
1 14 11 16
9 10 3 12
13 6 15 8
13 2 7 4
```

Then, the output should be

```
16 12 15 13   //Max of each row
1 2 3 4       //Min of each column
```

EDIT: Here is the revised code that works.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void getMax(int n, int a[][n])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int max = a[i][0];
        for (int j = 1; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (a[i][j] > max)
                max = a[i][j];
        }
        printf("%d ",max);
    }
}

void getMin(int n, int b[][n])
{

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int min = b[0][i];
        for (int j = 1; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (b[j][i] < min)
                min = b[j][i];
        }
        printf("%d ",min);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int r;
    scanf("%d", &r);
    int a[r][r];
    for(int i=0; i<r; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<r; j++)
            {
                scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
            }
        }

    getMax(r,a);
    printf("\n");
    getMin(r,a);
    printf("\n");
}
```

This is my OLD code that did not work. Turns out I don't have to use MAX. Replace the a[][MAX] to a[][n].

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 1000

void getMax(int a[][MAX], int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int max = a[i][0];
        for (int j = 1; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (a[i][j] > max)
                max = a[i][j];
        }
        printf("%d ",max);
    }
}

void getMin(int b[][MAX], int n)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int min = b[0][i];
        for (int j = 1; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (b[j][i] < min)
                min = b[j][i];
        }
        printf("%d ",min);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int r;
    scanf("%d", &r);
    int a[r][r];
    for(int i=0; i<r; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<r; j++)
            {
                scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
            }
        }

    getMax(a,r);
    printf("\n");
    getMin(a,r);
}
```

Can anybody point out what I did wrong? 
Thank you!

Comment: What does the compiler say? `r` will need to be `MAX` for the array indexing to align correctly in the functions. So the functions should be `void getMax(int n, int a[][n])` etc with appropriate adjustments.

Comment: @WeatherVane it can run, but the results are 16 822083584 858993459 482869899
1 0 11 16

Edit: after adjusting it with your suggestion, it worked perfectly! Thanks a lot!

Comment: `MAX` tells the compiler what the row length is for the 2D arrays. But it isn't `MAX` it is `n`.

Comment: Looks to me like you are accessing uninitialized memory. The output of min looks fine but max will show much higher values because uninitialized memory might just be random bits and thus often large numbers. Make sure that your array is actually n*n large.

Comment: On SO, the original code in a question should be retained, which you've done. (vs.) repeatedly revising it based on comments/answers you receive. If you _had_ done this, this would make the question seem nonsensical. Normally, you don't have to, but, if you want to post your revised/final code [fixed with the responses], the usual/accepted way is for you to post an _answer_ to your question and put it there. This maintains the Q & A format

Comment: @Craig Estey thanks for the input. As you can see, I am very new to SO, and this is my first question. I will edit it when I have time so that it's easier to look through. :)